# Octave 3.8.0 - package installation error in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, package, octave

I am trying to install some packages in Octave however, I am getting errors. Any help will be much appreciated. I tried this from Octave home directory. (I have also tried: pkg install general-1.3.4.tar.gz)

```
octave:1> pkg install -forge general
In file included from /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.7.3/include/stdint.h:3:0,
             from /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave/oct-conf-post.h:167,
             from /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave/config.h:3351,
             from /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave/../octave/oct.h:31,
             from SHA1.cc:19:
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.7.3/include-fixed/stdint.h:27:32: fatal error: sys/_types/_int8_t.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [SHA1.oct] Error 1
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/mkoctfile-3.8.0 SHA1.cc

pkg: error running `make' for the general package.
error: called from 'configure_make' in file /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/configure_make.m near line 82, column 9
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/install.m at line 199, column 5
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 394, column 9
```

Answer (score 3):

Running the following command on a new terminal window solved it for me on the command line and gui based versions:

xcode-select --install

Answer (score 2):

I have found a workaround from other sites on the web:

I was having the same issue when trying to install the Octave Signal Package without success. The following finally appears to be working.

1. code-select --install from the Terminal window to install the command line tools
2. Install MacPorts for Mac. This is a standard installer that you can download from Macports.
3. sudo port install gcc48 --> This is a Fortran compiler, which is necessary for installing octave-general
4. sudo port install octave-general [NOTE: THIS TOOK A *VERY* LONG TIME, and I had to disable Spotlight indexing...Hours on a Macbook Pro]
5. sudo port install octave-control
6. sudo port install octave-signal

Comment: This led me in the right direction, though it was not enough. I will later post a detailed answer on how I succeeded with it.

Comment: @Artem: sorry, did not make it to creating a detailed post. Looking back at my notes, step 4 above failed a few times due to missing dependencies. Installing them and running the port install again worked. Then I had to install a few graphics packages before I got the GUI mode running.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar problems with octave 3.8.0 and Yosemite

> > pkg install /Users/Andrew/Downloads/odepkg-0.8.4.tar.gz
> >     configure: error: in `/var/tmp/oct-ZcfViL/odepkg/src':
> >     configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> >     See`config.log' for more details
> >     checking for gcc... /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/gcc-mp-4.7
> >     checking whether the C compiler works... no
> >
> > pkg: error running the configure script for odepkg.
> >     error: called from 'configure_make' in file /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/configure_make.m near line 72, column 9
> >     error: called from:
> >     error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/install.m at line 199, column 5
> >     error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 394, column 9

I have the xcode command line tools installed.